# Bread machine for mixing Challah/Recipe for bread machine mixed Challah

Tags: bread, challah-shabbat-bread

The last time I tried to make [challah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challah) I failed, because it wouldn't rise in the bread machine and just stayed kind of watery. Before I ask this, is Challah allowed to be mixed in a bread machine? If not, please give me some advice.

I can't seem to find the right recipe, and I would really like to make my own *challah,* since all I've been using for Shabbat kiddush etc. is just a normal loaf of bread, and it's getting frustrating. (I don't live near any Jewish people or near a kosher store that stocks *challah* or anything.)

Does anyone know any good recipes or just ways to do it? 
I'm new to bread making, but I'd like to fulfill the mitzvah to have some yummy *challah* for Shabbat!

Comment: Challah can be any type of bread. It is customary to plait it. So just use a recipe you like from the instructions for your bread machine. Experience teaches that you must be exact with the quantities you use.

Comment: I suppose it's totally off-topic, but here's my (very simple) dough recipe: 650 g flour, 325 ml water, 25 ml oil, 1 heaping tablespoon of sugar, 1 ("flat") tablespoon of salt, 25 g of fresh yeast (or read the instruction if instant). Others add different stuff, but this is the simplest one.

Comment: Another recipe with [imperial units](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/the-nosher/how-to-make-challah)

Comment: Hi Untitled and welcome to MY! The site policy is that Jewish life questions - questions that might not be directly related to Judaism but it’s reasonable to expect someone who lives a Jewish life to have an answer to it - are entirely on-topic. As such, this is a perfectly fine question to ask here. Thank you for bringing this question here, and I hope to see you around!

Comment: @doniel this is a halakha question. Can challah be kneaded in a bread machine

Comment: @DoubleAA I was addressing the second question. The first question I don’t think anyone thought would be a problem.